# Как запустить команду в powershell с правами администратора?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Возможно ли выполнить команду в powershell с правами администратора, если powershell запущена без прав администратора?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы запустили powerShell без прав администратора, то коммандно можно перейти в командную строку для администратора:

```
PS> Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

либо если у вас скрипт запущен без соответствующих прав, то добавьте туда эти строки:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/running-a-command-as-administrator-using-powershell) есть подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Как можно убрать подтверждение на внесение изменений?

Comment: @МатвейИссаков, о каком подтверждении идет речь?

Comment: При выполнении скрипта появляется диалоговое окно с предупреждением о внесении изменений в систему программой powershell.

Comment: так вы хотите запустить от админа скрипт, конечно будет подтверждение)) можно попробовать передать в это окно программное нажатие на кнопку "да" или как там она называется

Comment: А как сделать программное нажатие на кнопку в скрипте?